# Facebook share - corona sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, lua, coronasdk

I have a quick question about using Facebook to post Status and app store links etc by clicking on a button during the game over screen using Corona SDK and LUA.

I understand that I need to get a fbAppID in order to use Facebook share but can I use it with a unfinished app, just for testing on device whether the Facebook share feature works properly?

Do I also need to get my app approved by Facebook in order to use it? won't that require the game to be finished and ready for launch?

If anyone has any good tutorials or useful tips on getting this feature to work then id love to hear it. I really wanna use this feature in my game but am very confused in the different methods that need to be done correctly, and when so.

Im reading the Ghost vs Monsters sample code to get a rough idea but am still confused on the Facebook developer side of things.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re "*get a fbAppID in order to use Facebook share but can I use it with a unfinished app*": As per the [Facebook Portal Setup docs](http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/social/setupFacebook/index.html),

> Once registered, you must set up your app with Facebook to receive a unique App ID. You can do this even if your app isn't yet complete.

This makes sense because the two systems are completely separate: as long as your app can speak the Facebook API, it can participate, regardless of what else is in it, Facebook doesn't care.

Re "*Do I also need to get my app approved by Facebook*": you may need to get the "idea" of your app approved, and to accept an agreement that will identify what you are allowed and not allowed to do with your app (anything illegal or anything that violates the Facebook end user agreement, etc), but Facebook will not try out your app to determine if it is sufficiently mature, why would they care, the only thing Facebook cares about is to generate traffic on their site, provide date for its social network, and do so within the bounds of the law and the EULA. Please post specific evidence to the contrary if you have some, or specific experience you have had.